# In simple pendulum problem, how to change Initial boundary conditions polar into cartesian coordinate

Tags: dynamics

The problem is

Using the equations of motion for the simple pendulum in cartesian coordinates (Eq.(3.7)), numarically integrate the trajectory for the initial conditions

```
(\[Theta][0], \[Theta]'[0]) = (0.1, 0)
```

Plot the pendulum angle theta[t] and the pendulum length l[t]=sqrt[x[t]^2+y[t]^2] as a function of time.
The equation (3.7) is

```
x''[t] == (-x[t] x'[t]^2 - x[t] y'[t]^2 + x[t] y[t] g)/l[t]^2
y''[t] == (-y[t] x'[t]^2 - y[t] y'[t]^2 - x[t]^2 g)/l[t]^2
```

At first i try to make EOM(equation of motion) only express for x[t] and y[t]. So use l[t]=sqrt[x[t]^2+y[t]^2]]. And in this problem the initial boundary condition expressed polar coordinate, sine i try to change IBC(Initial Boundary Condition) as

```
\[Theta][t] == ArcTan[y[t]/x[t]]; 
Tan[\[Theta][t]] == Sin[\[Theta][t]]/Cos[\[Theta][t]] == y[t]/x[t]
```

Since,

```
y[0]=Sin[\[Theta][0]]
x[0]=Cos[\[Theta][0]]
```

Actually I don't know that another two IBC correctly.

there is my process by using Mathematica and solutions what i want to plot. Actually I just try to make to plot similarly to solution. So i was assumed the one of IBC.

[image]

That is, I want to know method of changing IBC, and i want to plot the graph in solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two second order differential equations.  Thus, you need 4 initial conditions.  You already have half of them:
$x(t)=l \sin(\theta(t))$ and $\theta(0)=0.1$ has given you $x(0)$, and similarly $y(0)$.  Now you just need to figure out $x'(0)$.  This is actually fairly easy.  Just calculate the derivative of $x$ and evaluate at $t=0$.  You already have the expression for $x(t)$.  Just take derivative using chain rule.  i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = \frac{d}{dt} ( l \sin(\theta(t))) = l \frac{d}{dt}\sin(\theta(t)) = l \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin(\theta)\frac{d}{dt} \theta(t) $.  I think you should be able to work this out.  Once you have that, just evaluate at $t=0$ and then do the same for $y$.

(as an aside, I would not call these "initial boundary conditions", I would just call them "initial conditions". Usually the word "boundary" is reserved for partial differential equations where the variables are spatial.  This is just an ordinary differential equation where the variable is time.  So I'd say "initial condition")

Comment: +1: But you can also have boundary value problems for ODEs.